# What is the output voltage of MCP23017 IO expander?

Tags: raspberry-pi, vibration-motor

I am planning to power small vibration motors (17-20 mA max rating) once at a time through an MCP23017 port expander board to connected to a RPi 3 model B and driven by I2C.
The operating voltage of the micromotors is 2.4~3.6 V. However I don't understand what is the voltage on the output pins of the MCP23017. An idea?

Comment: By better looking at the datasheet the output voltage on the GPIOs should be:
1-Output low voltage max 0.6 V 
2-Output high voltage min VDD-0.7 V.
Any contraindications of running those motors?

Answer (score 1):

You can power the MCP23017 with 3.3V and control it via I2C but you will need at least an extra transistor connected to one pin of this chip to control the motor:
[image]

And you may actually want to use something like an H-bridge if you want to change the direction.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to avoid the transistors/shift registers if possible. That's why I selected very low current motors. I have been thinking that since the output pins of the MCP23017 can source up to 25mA, running the motors that have a max rating of 20mA should be fine in a similar fashion to how you can directly power LEDs without transistors. Could you explain me why this isn't possible? Also I was thinking I could run them at slightly lower voltage to reduce current draw by a tad.